# How can I pass predefined variable to playbook's "- hosts: "POD_'+VARIABLE+'_master_sn""

Tags: ansible

I have a file named "all" under group_vars with predefined variable, the value of which can be changed, let say, from "C" to "D' depends on what I need:

```
VARIABLE: C
```

Also, I have a task under my playbook:

```
- hosts: "POD_'+VARIABLE+'_master_sn"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: sn_static_hosts
        tasks_from: remove
```

As you can see, I want to perform concatenation, but getting this:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: POD_'+source_pod_name_capital_letter+'_master_sn
```

I have tried to play with brackets, removed/added "+" etc, but got only warnings or errors.

Is that possible to have this kind of concatenation?

UPDATE:

I need to read VARIABLE from some pre-defined file, not from the console.

Comment: `"{{ 'POD_' + source_pod_name_capital_letter + '_master_sn' }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks, but this does not work. The VARIABLE is undefined for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
- hosts: "POD_{{VARIABLE}}_master_sn"
  tasks:
  - include_role:
     name: sn_static_hosts
     tasks_from: remove
```

Below is how I tested with localhost:

Playbook

```
- hosts: "loc{{var}}host"
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "var=al"
```

Output:

> PLAY [localhost]

Comment: Thanks smily, but I need to read VARIABLE from some pre-defined file, not from the console.